# Opening/closing sql connection - redundant code

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I was wondering what is the most basic way to avoid the following.

```vb
    con.ConnectionString = connection_String
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con

    'database interaction here

    cmd.Close()
```

I keep making those lines all over in my project, but I figure there has to be a better way to save on typing this over and over. It makes the code look even more sloppy than it already is!

Ended up with this, works well for me. Thanks for the help :)

```
Public Sub connectionState()
    If con.State = 0 Then
        con.ConnectionString = connection_String
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
    Else
        con.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question — unless you're about to close it.

Comment: In normal cases, it is better to have one connection to the database that you use for the duration of your program.

Comment: I posted the solution and I figured the title was clear enough, if you want to edit the post, you could at least leave the solution in there so the next guy can see it.

Comment: @dan1111 - Are you suggesting keeping an _open_ connection to the database at all times?  If so, that's not considered "better" in most circles because it negatively affects scalability and doesn't take advantage of connection pooling.

Comment: Your final function smells like you've got some design issues... that your class is much larger than it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where a lot of programmers are tempted to create a "database layer" with a variations on method signatures that look like this:

```
Public DataSet ExecuteSQL(ByVal sql As String) As DataSet
```

That allows you to isolate all that boilerplate connection code in one place. An sql command string goes in, and data comes out. Easy.

*Don't do it!*

This is headed in the right direction, but has one very big flaw: it forces you to use string manipulation to substitute parameter values into your sql queries. That leads to horrible sql injection security vulnerabilities.

Instead, make sure you include some mechanism in your methods to prompt for the sql parameters separately. This usually comes in the form of an additional argument to the function, and could be as simple as an array of KeyValuePairs. If you're comfortable with lambdas, my preferred pattern looks like this:

```
Public Iterator Function GetData(Of T)(ByVal sql As String, ByVal addParameters As Action(Of SqlParameterCollection), ByVal translate As Func(Of IDatarecord, T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        addParameters(cmd.Parameters)

        cn.Open()
        Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While rdr.Read()
                Yield(translate(rdr))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

To call that function, you would do something like this:

```
Dim bigCustomers = GetData("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE SalesTotal > @MinSalesTotal", _
                   Sub(p) p.Add("@MinSalesTotal", SqlDbType.Decimal, 1000000), _
                   MyCustomerClass.FromIDataRecord)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a class ( a singleton class ), and write the database connection syntax code and exceptions in that class, then call one object to the main class to create the database connection, that's the best way in performance and keep writing the same code on and on...

Comment: A singleton is a poor choice here. It limits you to one thread for database access. I made that mistake once. Just once.

Comment: I understand that, I don't think it's considered as a mistake but a choice to take in specific projects using DB

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `using block`, using execute dispose on non managed object in the end of treatment.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Little advanced for me, I don't doubt it would be useful though. I am just trying to stay afloat here ;)

Appreciate it though!

Comment: I'am happy to help you Meowbits, you can also use just using blok