# Object reference not set to a instance of an Object

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that fills with data, and a view button which gives more details of the record choosen by the user. I cannot figure out why I am getting the error:

> Object reference not set to a instance of an Object

I have narrowed it down to between my two message boxes. The First message box comes up but it crashes before the second. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Protected Sub CountAlerts_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles CountAlerts.RowCommand
    If (e.CommandName = "Viewdtails") Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim NDC, Unit, Cell, DTTM, prod, Query, _startdt, _enddt As String
        Dim DS As DataSet

        NDC = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("NDC")
        Cell = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("Cell")
        Unit = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("Unit")
        DTTM = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("TimeDate")
        prod = CountAlerts.DataKeys(index).Values("ProductDesc")

        _startdt = If(StartDate.Text = "", DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, System.DateTime.Now).ToShortDateString, StartDate.Text)
        _enddt = If(EndDate.Text = "", System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString, EndDate.Text)
        For Each irow As GridViewRow In CycleCountAlerts.Rows
            If irow.Attributes("class") = "highlight" Then
                irow.Attributes.Remove("class")
            End If
        Next

        CountAlerts.Rows(index).Attributes("class") = "highlight"
        Query = " EXEC [Audits].[dbo].[ExceptionDetailsCombined] '" & NDC & "', '" & Cell & "', '" & Unit & "', '" & DTTM & "', '" & Master.CF_User.Viewing & "' "
        DS = SelectQuery(Query)

        If (DS.Tables.Count > 0) Then
            unitbox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Unit")
            cellbx.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Cell")
            ndcbox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("NDC")
            namebox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ProductDesc")
            cycdttmbx.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TimeDate")
            cycusr.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("CycUser")
            todisp.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TODISPSIZE")
            topkgbox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TOPKGSIZE")
            toqtybx.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TOQTY")
            FRQTYbx.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("FRQTY")
            TextBox2.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ActualQTY")
            cycvarqbox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("CYCLEVARQTY")
            CycleVarPctbx.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("CYCLEVARPCT")
            alertrsnbx.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("AlertReason")
            combox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("AcceptComment")
            acusr.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("AcceptUser")
            acctime.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("AcceptTime")
            accstatbx.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("AcceptStatus")
            displbl.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Disposition")
        End If

        Query = " EXEC [CF_Audits].[dbo].[CommentTrackerCombined] '" & Master.CF_User.EmployeeID & "', '" & NDC & "', '" & Cell & "', '" & Unit & "', '" & _startdt & "', '" & _enddt & "', '" & Master.CF_User.Viewing & "' "
        DS = SelectQuery(Query)

        If (DS.Tables.Count > 0) Then
            ExceptionHist_GV.DataSource = DS
            ExceptionHist_GV.DataBind()
            ExceptionHist_GV.UseAccessibleHeader = True
            MsgBox("except gv header") 'Runs up to here. 
            ExceptionHist_GV.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
            MsgBox("except gv header 2") ' Does not make it to here.
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no line number along with the error?

Comment: Your Query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You're practically begging to get hacked. I suspect your `SelectQuery()` method is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12801931/3043

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `TableRowSection` or `TableRowSection.TableHeader` is/are `Nothing`

Check that these are initialised before using them

```
If MsgBox("except gv header") 
If Not TableRowSection Is Nothing AndAlso Not TableRowSection.TableHeader Is Nothing Then
    ExceptionHist_GV.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
Else
    MsgBox "How did we get here?"
End If
MsgBox("except gv header 2")
```

If you see the message "How did we get here" that indicates you have not initialised you object

Answer (score 0):

In object orientated languages you need to instantiate an object before you can use it.

Something in this line:

```
        ExceptionHist_GV.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
```

has not been instantiated with the `new` keyword. You can find out exactly what by checking the details of the `Exception` which was thrown.

It will be either `ExceptionHist_GV` or `TableRowSection`.

Comment: I actually found that I needed to include an AndAlso to the line: (DS.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

Comment: @user2354956 - I can't see how that would've made a difference.